# Eclipse hangs while debugging

Tags: eclipse, gwt, fedora

I searched lot about this topics but can't find a proper solution.

I am using eclipse 3.6 Helios version with operating system fedora15. In my application I am using GWT2.4 for front end development.

Now while I work with debug mode and want to debug at some point at the same time eclipse hangs for 3-4 mins.It resumes after and again start to debug process.

I am using this eclipse from last 3 years with windows but not faced this issue.In fedora I am using it from last 4 months and this problems stated to occur from last one month.

I am not getting what is the issues with eclipse.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't want to seem unhelpful but in my experience, eclipse is prone to this sort of unusual behaviour over time, and its solved simply by taking a fresh copy. I would be interested to see if someone can suggest a decent solution to this.

Comment: First thing u r using Fedora..lol..I got tired with it and shifted to suse.
May be u r using some remote debugger plz check it out.because such situations can occur in case of remote debugger.

Comment: Yes I am using fedora..But I am not using any remote debugger...I m using debug of eclipse only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using GWT 2.4 and I think you might be working with UI.xml too... There is a tag in each ui.xml at the top like

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
```

Which means eclipse is going to get that xhtml.ent file each time and there is a issue in GWT eclipse plugin have a look to below link

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5265

There is one comment which says

```
For me, removing 
SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent"
and saving the document, 
solves the problem.. 
maybe it is needed for something, so better you copy that locally somewhere, and link that.
```

Try it out and let me know.

Comment: Well, I agree on somewhat level on this. But what about those panels which are not created using "ui:UiBinder" ?

Answer (score 3):

Is this something that happens with different projects/code, or is it the same code that causes freezes? I've had issues where threads have started in the background and caused problems.

You say "(...) hangs for 3-4 mins.It resumes after and again start to debug process.", what do you mean? Does it continue to debug and move to the next line, or is there a crash and it restarts?

How long has it been since you changed workspace? I've found this, rather than the Eclipse installation, to be an issue over time. Create a new workspace folder, export all your projects and preferences and start fresh.

Comment: thanks for reply.It is different code every time.But one thing is common it is code for client side (i.e GWT side) not for server side.One it hangs 3-4 mins then it move to next line.I can try with new workspace as it is 2-3 months old

Comment: In that case, I dont think a new workspace will make any drastic change. In my situations the workspace had been around since Ye Olde Times of Eclipse 3.5.0...
Seems more likely that this is an issue with GWT. Perhaps this is a known bug. Try updating GWT.

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced the exact same problem on a less-powerful notebook I had to use.
Try one of the following

- Download the [latest](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-371/indigosr1) Eclipse version (It needs, just as helios, a lot of RAM and CPU because it's based on a new "architekture", in contrast to, for instance, galileo)
- Make sure you are using the latest [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u2-download-1377129.html) and JRE
- Download Eclipse [Galileo](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/galileo/sr2), which does require pretty less resources and goes still very very fine with most projects!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are experiencing the features of the latest Eclipse arch. In the latest versions of Eclipse I have noticed that the more plugins and add-ons you have installed, the slower the environment runs. There are a lot of similar posts regarding performance on the new platform

I have removed all but the plugins I am using and never install anything not needed into the Eclipse environment.

Answer (score 0):

I "may" have experience this. Not sure.  Suddenly started working again.  I was getting a hang every time I would try to debug an app, in the part of the code (inside GWT) that creates a "table" element. Could be that there is something that just takes a while and you just have to "wait it out" the when it happens.  Go get a cup of coffee, type thing.  anyway I HAD stepped deep into the GWT code, plenty so I'm convinced it IS a GWT issue of some kind.

I was thinking it was some infinite recursion possibly in the logging system (like logger code accidentally trying to log itself, and going into loop?).  Also there's a 50/50 chance that it was simply clicking on 'run' instead of 'debug' made it start working again.  So at least try that if you have problems. My gut instinct and 30yrs programming under my belt tells me it's logger related.  I can rule out "slow computers" because I never had this happen until I got a new machien which is Dell XPS, Core i7, 8 GB ram, and massive disk.  So I wouldn't blame hardware, or Eclipse bloat.